# How to uninstall postgreSQL from my local computer

Tags: postgresql

I thought I deleted postgres from my computer but when I look at pgAdmin, the server still shows up. I've deleted the application as well as the file I downloaded but for some reason I still see and have access to the server. I've tried removing the server from pgAdmin and that doesnt seem to work (when I restart pgAdmin, I see the Server again). Does anyone know how to go about deleting?

I deleted the application.
Deleted the downloaded file.
Checked libraries in terminal and dont see anything specific to Postgres

Comment: That it still shows up in pgAdmin4 means nothing.  Remove it from pgAdmin4 if you want it to stop showing up there.  Now if you can still make that entry become active, that would indicate a problem.

Comment: Yea, it does seem like I can still make that server active. When I click on that server and enter my password I have access to the databases associated. And when I "remove" it and restart pgAdmin, it just shows up again. 

And I dont know if this makes any difference or not but I am utilizing the desktop app for pgAdmin. Not the web app.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - Although I deleted the application and the download package, it only removed the downloaded package and not the installed PostgreSQL server or its associated data directory.

So, from my terminal I had to run "open /Library/PostgreSQL/15/uninstall-postgresql.app"